# Two django form fields using SelectDateWidget

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have `ContactView` in `forms.py` set upped like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, extras
from .models import ContactForm
from django import forms
from django_countries.widgets import CountrySelectWidget
import datetime


class ContactView(ModelForm):

    """Docstring for ContactView. """
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2025, 1939, -1)))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    move_in_date, move_out_date = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(),
                                                  initial=datetime.date.today())

    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'topic', 'message',
                  'birthdate', 'move_in_date', 'move_out_date',
                  'country']
        model = ContactForm
        widgets = {'country': CountrySelectWidget()
```

}

How can `move_in_date` and `move_out_date` use `SelectDateWidget`, (I want this, because I need to display this widget twice) this here is giving me a nice `TypeError`, because `DateField` is not iterable.
I don't want them written like this either, even do this works, but *Smells on bad code*.

```
  move_in_date = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(), initial=datetime.date.today())
  move_out_date = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(), initial=datetime.date.today())
```

Question is how to write this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
move_in_date, move_out_date = ...
```

You need two variables on the right side (or an iterable with two elements) for the assignment to work. This is the reason you're getting the error `DateField` is not iterable. You can define DateField on the right side twice and the error will go away.

If you're trying to remove duplication in your code, you simply factor out the common code into a function:

```
def get_move_date_field():
    """ return a DateField suitable for move_in and move_out """
    return forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(), initial=datetime.date.today())

class ContactView(ModelForm):
    ....
    move_in_date = get_move_date_field()
    move_out_date = get_move_date_field()
```

Comment: It seems to me that I need to practise more, this is some standard python stuff, and a vary good answer, thanks.